# How to get the current block height for a coin in BitGo API?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I am trying to figure out a way to get the current blockchain information from BitGo API.
I am using BitGo Express and still couldn't find any endpoints that would return me the latest block information for a given coin.

If bitgo does not provide such an endpoint, which service would you recommend to get these information?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with BitGo API, but for interact with bitcoin, litecoin, dash, doge and ethereum blockchains you can use [Blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/).

For get current blockchain info have a look at https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#chain-endpoint